# Add Classpath for jdbc driver under windows 7

Tags: jdbc

I read out this manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html) and could not find which string exactly I should set under environment variables and I could not find any mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar file after installing the driver via mysql-connector-java-gpl-5.1.26. I tried

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;path\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
```

But I have no idea how to replace path and I cant find this jar in my computer.

Comment: Are you using web application or standard java application?

Comment: I need it for [this](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2010/09/connecting-to-sql-server-from-r-using-rjdbc/), but the problem was solved after I found the file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar" in my computer. So after I replaced the wildcard path it worked.